# Will the unified API return information from Azure?

Tags: azure, office365

I've been researching the new unified API for office365 (graph.microsoft.com). Currently one can authenticate to it using an organisationalID and it will return information from emails-from-exchange/OneDrive4Business/Skype4Business(future)/calendar-from-exchange/exchange-contacts/etc...

The ability to surface such a plethora of information from one endpoint strikes me as being hugely valuable. In the future I'd really like to see information relating to Azure be surfaced in here also. For example, I'd love to use graph.microsoft.com to access lists of:

- Azure storage accounts
- Azure SQL DB servers and databases
- Azure SQL DB firewall rules
- Azure ML experiments
- Countless other things

Are such things on the roadmap?

Comment: Great question....for the Microsoft Team. Given they're placing a large focus on the [WAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722415.aspx), I would assume its a ways out (if ever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a great question, and it's great to see such enthusiasm around a single endpoint surfacing this information.  We're not sure when Azure resource providers would be a part of the unified API, but it would be great to have them.  There are a number of other teams who are very interested, and in general we've been pretty focused on user or person centric developer experiences here as you should be able to see from Yina Arena's //Build or Ignite presentations.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Dan. I actually had a conversation on Twitter with Chris Johnson about this and he raised the point that the unified API is person-centric. I replied that that's exactly the reason that I would like to see Azure stuff in there. Here's our conversation: https://twitter.com/jamiet/timelines/600555333380141056

I also notice you and I have ended up on an email thread about this so perhaps we could discuss offline.